# std::function как параметр шаблона

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Шаблон принимает три аргумента, третий лямбда на основе первых двух:

```
namespace Util {
template< class TObject,
          class TConfig,
          std:: template function<typename TObject (const typename TConfig& )> TCreateFunctor >
class Builder{
public:
    Builder(const TConfig& cfg): _Create(TCreateFunctor), m_cfg(&cfg)
    {}
    Builder() : _Create(TCreateFunctor), m_cfg(0)
    {}
    virtual ~Builder() = default;
    TObject Create(const TConfig& cfg){
        m_cfg = &cfg;
        return _Create(*m_cfg);
    }
    TObject Create(){
        poco_check_ptr(m_cfg);
        return _Create(*m_cfg);
    }
    void Reset(const TConfig& cfg){
        m_cfg = &cfg;
    }
private:
    typedef std::function< TObject(const TConfig& cfg)> TFuncCreator;
    TFuncCreator _Create;
    const TConfig* m_cfg;
};
}
```

Не компилируется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Согласно [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters), формальный параметр шаблона, на являющийся типом, должен сам иметь один из следующих типов: целочисленный тип, enum, указатель на объект или функцию, lvalue-ссылка на объект или функцию, указатель на поле или функцию-член, `std::nullptr_t`.

Ваш тип не попал в список.

---

Почему бы вам просто не убрать этот параметр шаблона, и не передавать значение ещё одним параметром в конструктор?

Comment: Хотел избавится от переписывания конструкторов. Первоначальный вариант предполагал виртуальный метод Create и наследование.

Comment: Тоже вариант, по идее. Хотя конечно композиция по идее лучше наследования.